# I seem to have painted a target on my back

Tags: discussion, new-users

So we've had a new user come through with some bad grammar and some poorly worded answers. No biggie, it happens.

I edited 3-4 of his posts, noticed they were all from the same user and [mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112569/is-it-a-glitch-that-all-three-legs-of-blue-were-broken-simultaneously-and-it-sti/121175#121175) on one of them that he should try to be more fluent in his questions & answers.

To which I log in today with a [suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/40150) from him, basically defacing the answer. I also had a down vote on another question, presumably from the same user.

I know its probably not much to go on, but I've never come across something like this sort of passive aggressive behaviour on Stack Exchange before, and I'm a bit unsure how to respond.

Do I just continue on my merry way, "nothing to see here", and hope he grows tired of it? Do I ask him to stop? Or can I take action some other way?

**Edit:**

It seems in this case it was just a bit of misplaced confusion, we've [made amends](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85840/do-adaptive-shields-adapt-to-non-elemental-damage/121178#comment163959_121178), so this should be the end of it. It's nice to have a positive outcome :)

Comment: Your downvote can't have come from the user because he doesn't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: You probably got downvoted by Sonic.

Comment: @Wipqozn - Blast that hedgehog!

Comment: There are smarts built in to stack exchange that detect when a user voting on posts of the same user excessively. The details of this are kept secret so that it's harder to circumvent. All in all he cannot harm you too much.

Comment: fwiw you weren't the only one tho have left a comment like that on his posts.

Comment: @spartacus - No it wasn't, I think it was just a bit of culture shock to have practically all of his posts edited or downvoted. We've cleared up the confusion now, see my edit.

Comment: That awkward moment when you the defaced answer he linked was the one on your question >_<

Comment: @avestar101 - Heh, try the awkward moment when you enter the Suggested Edit review queue and you're reviewing your own answer ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've already alerted us to it and that's about all you need to worry about. Hopefully.

I wish Slap On the Wrist Through Internet Protocol was a thing that existed.

Comment: Weeeeeeeell ... You know ... It's actually possible to ... I think I'll shut up now.

Comment: Next IETF RFC: Slap On The Wrist/Internet Protocol (SOTW/IP). Make it happen!

Comment: @FEichinger Thanks, Krieger.